# Build a C library With a shared singleton class

Tags: c, memory, dll, singleton

I have a customized memory allocator, which is a singleton class (contains static variable). This memory allocator is shared across the project.

Now the project will include a library. It turns out to that the library has its own copy of the memory allocator (a separate copy of the static variable)

How can I make the library share the same single static variable with the project?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ??? C does not have classes.  You'll have to provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do to get any useful help.

Comment: By singleton class, I mean static variable. The functions of the class modify such variable so that the variable is shared across the project.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the project will include a library. It turns out to that the
> library has its own copy of the memory allocator (a separate copy of
> the static variable)
>
> How can I make the library share the same single static variable with
> the project?

File-scope static variables have internal linkage, which means that they cannot be accessed by name by functions appearing in different translation units.  Functions in the same translation unit can access them, however, including on behalf of callers from other TUs.  Thus, you share such variables by sharing the functions that directly or indirectly manipulate them.

But if you have a program that already includes a set of functions that manipulate one copy of such a variable and you want to link it with a library containing its own set of the same functions then it gets complicated.  And if the library in question is a shared library (a.k.a. a DLL) then it gets even more complicated.  The best advice is probably "don't do that."

In your case, I would probably factor out the allocator into its own, separate library, and have all comers link against that.  That way, there is only one copy of the variable in question in the first place.